# How SQL queries may be optimized

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a SQL Server table `Top_Research_Areas` that contains data like i.e.

```
aid     res_category_id    research_area            Paper_Count     
---------------------------------------------------------------
2937    33                 markov chain             3               
2937    33                 markov decision process  1               
2937    1                  linear system            1               
11120   29                 aspect oriented prog     4               
11120   1                  graph cut                2               
11120   1                  optimization problem     2               
12403   2                  differential equation    7               
12403   1                  data structure           2               
12403   1                  problem solving          1               
35786   1                  complete graphs          11              
35786   1                  graph cut                10              
35786   NULL               NULL                     2               
49261   3                  finite automata          6               
49261   3                  finite element           2               
49261   14                 database                 2                
78841   5                  genetic programming      6               
78841   23                 active learning          2               
78841   28                 pattern matching         1
```

Now I want to select `pid` from another table i.e. `sub_aminer_paper` for the `aid`'s in table `Top_Research_Areas`, whereas table `sub_aminer_paper` contains columns i.e. `aid`, `pid`, `research_area`, `res_category_id` and some more columns too.

Moreover `Top_Research_Areas` only contains records for top_3 `research_area`'s whereas table `sub_aminer_paper` contains other than these records for `aid`'s in `Top_Research_Areas`.

I have used this query i.e.

```
SELECT
    aid, pid, research_area
FROM
    sub_aminer_paper 
WHERE
    aid IN (2937, 11120)
    AND research_area IN (SELECT
                              research_area 
                          FROM 
                              Top_Research_Areas 
                          WHERE
                              aid IN (2937, 11120))
ORDER BY aid ASC
```

Now the issue is, when retrieving `pid`'s from `sub_aminer_paper` by matching `research_area`'s in both tables, it gives me output e.g. if I retrieve records for two `aid`'s i.e. `2937` and `11120`, it gives me the output as:

[image]

We can see that the `Paper_Count` for Top 2 `aid`'s are `3+1+1+4+2+2` i.e. it should give `13` records, but it is giving `14` because of `research_area` i.e. `optimization problem` actually belongs to `aid` i.e. `11120` in table `Top_Research_Areas` but by using `IN` clause for matching `research_area` it is taking as a mixture of `research_area`'s of both `aid`'s, whereas I need `13` records in output instead of `14`.

How can it be handled ?

Please help and thanks!

Comment: There probably is a paper on "optimization problem"  for aid 2937 which isn't logged in top_research_Areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is a paper on "optimization problem"  for aid 2937 which isn't logged in top_research_Areas.

See id this helps :  select from sub_aminer_paper where the combination of (aid,research_area) exists,

```
SELECT
    sap.aid, sap.pid, sap.research_area
FROM
    sub_aminer_paper  sap
WHERE
  sap.AID IN (2937, 11120) --- For indexing which I'm assuming this column has
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Top_Research_Areas tra WHERE tra.aid = sap.aid and tra.research_area = sap.research_area and tra.aid in (2937,11120))
```

Comment: @Amir-- Thanks you much, this query works what intended